# Reuse variadic types

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

In the following C++14 code, I would like to create a container of PossibleTypes using variadic templates. Next, I would like to create another container with a member tuple of the types previously specified.

How would one go about in doing so? I would like to have Foo contain a tuple of  < int, double >, just as the templated types of topics.

Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... T>
struct PossibleTypes {};

PossibleTypes<int,double> topics;

template <typename... T>
struct Foo{
    std::tuple<T...> member;
};

int main(){
    Foo<??(topics)??> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this.  You don't have to understand them all, just find one that has the features you want.

Here are three very different ways to do this.

## Transcribe from an instance to a template

```
template<class Src, template<class...>class Dest>
struct transcribe;
template<class Src, template<class...>class Dest>
using transcribe_t=typename transcribe<Src,Dest>::type;

template<template<class...>class Src, class...Ts, template<class...>class Dest>
struct transcribe<Src<Ts...>, Dest>{
  using type=Dest<Ts...>;
};
```

then:

```
transcribe_t<decltype(topics), Foo> x;
```

## Intrusively by modifying Foo

This can also be done intrusively by modifying `Foo` to take a bundle instead of a pack.

```
template <class Bundle>
struct Foo;

template <typename... T>
struct Foo<PossibleTypes<T...>>{
  std::tuple<T...> member;
};
```

or

```
template <template<class...>class Z, typename... T>
struct Foo<Z<T...>>{
  std::tuple<T...> member;
};
```

then:

```
Foo<decltype(topics)> x;
```

which can be much more practical if you aren't just passing in one set of `...` arguments.

## Value-based metaprogramming

We can also approach this using value-based metaprogramming:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {constexpr tag_t(){} using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct ztemplate_t {
  constexpr ztemplate_t() {}
  template<class...Ts> using apply=Z<Ts...>;
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr tag_t<Z<Ts...>> operator()(tag_t<Ts>...)const{ return {}; }
};
template<template<class...>class Z>
constexpr ztemplate_t<Z> ztemplate{};

template<class Tag>
using type=typename Tag::type;

template <class... T>
struct PossibleTypes {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  constexpr auto operator()(ztemplate_t<Z> z) const {
    return z(tag<T>...);
  }
};
```

giving us:

```
int main(){
  type<decltype( topics(ztemplate<Foo>) ) > x;
  return 0;
}
```

which is pretty slick.  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1c73a55764d5e2c).

`tag` lifts a type into a value.  `ztemplate` lifts a template into a value.

`ztemplate<some_template>( tag<T0>, tag<T1> )` returns a `tag` of the result of applying `some_template` to `T0, T1` like `tag_t<some_template<T0, T1>>`.

To move back to a type from a tag, we do a `type<decltype(some_tag_expression)>`.

I modified your `PossibleTypes` to also have an `operator()(ztemplate)` that applies the template to the types stored in `PossibleTypes`.

This kind of insanity works better as you do more and more type based manipulation, as value-based programming in C++ is much more expressive and easier to work with than the template syntax.

Comment: @mihai None of the above requires instantiating the object?  In every case I create the type.  Then  because your code did, I create an instance of the type (to prove it worked, I guess).  Remove then`x` and you have a type expression and no instance.  Use typedef or using to give it a name, or whatever.

Comment: Arf sorry. Problem in another part of the code. Works great!